# How would I make a plugin for video.js that adds and removes a triangle in the HTML title?

Tags: javascript, html, insert, video.js

Much like YouTube, when you hit play on the video the triangle shows up, and disappears when you pause it.  I'm not sure if this is something browser specific like Google Chrome has with those speakers in the tabs.

I want to know how would I do something like that for video.js

Comment: Make use of the events it provides: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md Add the triangle when `play` event fires, and remove it when `pause` or `ended` fire … something like that.

Answer (score 1):

From the video.js documentation (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/plugins.md) but slightly adapted to your case:

Step 1: Write some JavaScript

```
function trianglePlugin(options) {
  this.on('play', function(e) {
    window.originalDocumentTitle = document.title;
    document.title = "▶ " + document.title;
  });
  this.on('pause', function(e) {
    document.title = window.originalDocumentTitle;
  });
  this.on('ended', function(e) {
    document.title = window.originalDocumentTitle;
  });
};
```

Step 2: Register the plugin

```
videojs.plugin('trianglePlugin', trianglePlugin);
```

Step 3: Using a plugin

```
videojs('vidId', {
  plugins: {
    trianglePlugin: {
      exampleOptionWhichWeDontNeed: true
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit**
And if you actually mean the speaker icon (or icons in that location) in Chrome when you playback media with sound, that is browser specific and you have no way of controlling it.

Comment: For me the plugins section is too vauge and does not tell me where to paste the two other bits of text, or where to place/link the plugin so that video.js can read it.  Could you tell me where this stuff is placed?

Comment: That's pretty vague, too :p The section (as well as my answer) includes every bit of code you would need. The general procedure is you have included video.js somewhere on your page. Afterwards (it doesn't matter where) you add your JavaScript plugin code (step 1 and 2 from above). And now when you create your player instead of `var video = videojs('vidId');` you do it like shown in step 3 to pass your plugin (where `vidId` obviously is the ID of your video container). Should you already have a video object you could do `video.trianglePlugin({ exampleOption: true });`. That's it...

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the BigPlayButton component to your player.

```
videojs.Control = videojs.Component.extend();
videojs.Button = videojs.Control.extend();
videojs.PlayToggle = videojs.Button.extend();
// Adding a new control to the player
myPlayer.addChild('BigPlayButton');
```

Link to the video.js components guides
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/components.md

Hope this helps.